# Whats wrong with these 3 lines of python code?

Tags: python, string, input

I get an error after i put in an input, how can i fix it?

```
print('Type ROLL to roll for your stats')

roll = input()
if roll == ROLL:
    # ...
```

Comment: I think you should read a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/)...

Comment: What error do you get?
You might try raw_input()

Comment: my error is... Traceback (most revent call last): File "pyshell#o>", line 1, in <module> roll NameError: name 'roll' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have been more elaborate on the error. Anyway seeing your code, the indentation error is obvious. The `if` statement should not be indented but must be at the same level w.r.t the previous statement. Another error is that, in the comparison the string should be quoted like `'ROLL'`

```
print('Type ROLL to roll for your stats')

roll = input ()
if roll == 'ROLL':
    .......
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean `roll = raw_input('Type ROLL to roll for your stats')`

Comment: he's on python 3 (at least it looks like).

Comment: @JBernardo err, right, and i didn't see the syntax error...shame.

Comment: @Topro, I don't seem to see a Syntax Error. Either its a NameError or an IndentationError.

Comment: @Abhijit Indentation is part of Python's syntax, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
roll = input ('Type ROLL to roll for your stats ') # input block can contain a string to display
if roll == "ROLL": # This wasn't a string so Python3 will look for a variable named ROLL, which it won't find
```